# How can I get email back as a claim from oAuth using .net web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I seem to only have the oAuth ID (claim) sent back when a user logs into my dotnet web API project.

> claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

I am trying to get the email address (claim) of a logged in oAuth user. But looks like it doesn't get sent by default.

I have added the following Authentication set up in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"https://{config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:Domain")}/";
    options.Audience = config.GetValue<string>("Auth0:Audience");
    
});
```